# how to permanently activate/set the global event_scheduler to 1 in mysql

Tags: mysql, events

I have added a event to my mySQL db and it works fine, but the thing that is bothering me is that every now and then I have to set the mysql global variable to 1 so that my event is active.I log in as root user and have complete privileges (I use it for practice purpose)

Every time I log in to my mysql server I have to execute the following line

```
__set global event_scheduler=1__
```

can I set the event_scheduler variable permanently to 1?
I'm using mysql 5.1.50 - community

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, write `event_scheduler=on` somewhere under the `[mysqld]` section in the default mysql config file, usually `/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: thanks for the answer.Can you tell me more about the behavior of these global variables?

Comment: Check out the docs, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html

Answer (score 8):

If you are using WAMP **:**

Open its control panel by clicking on the WAMP icon -> mysql-> `my.ini`

Its location may be at:

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql{your.ver.sion}
```

Add **`EVENT_SCHEDULER=ON`** under ***[mysqld]*** - not *[mysql]* notice the "d" for daemon. Another tip to ascertain where you're adding is where your (default) server port is specified.

```
[mysqld]
port=3306
event_scheduler=on
```